# Autotools - Use Python 2.7 when Python 3 is available

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, archlinux, automake

I use Arch Linux. `python --version` returns Python 3.6.2, `python2 --version` (and `python2.7 --version`) returns Python 2.7.13. Automake searches for a python newer than 2.4 and finds `python` (3.6). The project doesn't work with python 3, though. `AM_PATH_PYTHON(<min-version>[,...])` doesn't allow one to specify a maximum version.

How can I have automake search for `python2` if `python` is too new? Or is there a better way to deal with this problem? Automake should still find `python` if it's the correct version because this build needs to be able to run on distributions that have older packages (for instance, Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until it's fixed upstream, I would do something like:

```
mkdir ~/autotools_bin/
ln -s /usr/bin/python2 ~/autotools_bin/python
export PATH="~/autotools_bin:$PATH"
```

Then it can only find python2 (named python) and your system isn't messed up, only processes you run with the changed PATH.

Answer (score 3):

`PYTHON` is setup by `AM_PATH_PYTHON` as a [precious variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html) and you can override its choice at configure time:

```
$ PYTHON=python2 ./configure
```